# Parsing Huge XML Files With 600M

Tags: python, xml, linux, fedora

Can please telle me if there are any way to parse an XML file(size = 600M) with unstagle /python
In Fact I use untangle.parse(file.xml) and I got error message :
Process finished with exit code 137

IS there any way to parse this file by bloc for example or other option used by the function untangle.parse() or a specific linux configuration...?

Thanks

Comment: Exit code 137 is the result of a SIGKILL.

Comment: You could have a look on Beautiful Soup. Their lxml parser it's very fast,and in a modern system (4GB+ RAM) you should have no problem parsing a 600MB file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xml** modules **sax**(Simple API for XML) parser.

SAX is a **streaming context** over XML and the Document is processed in the **linear fashion**.

This is advantageous when **DOM Tree** would consume too much of the memory as usual DOM implementations use **10 bytes of memory to represent 1 byte of XML**.

Sample code for doing some like this :

```
import xml.sax


def stream_gz_decompress(stream) : 
    dec = zlib.decompressobj(32 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    for chunk in stream : 
        rv = dec.decompress(chunk)
        if rv : 
            yield rv

class stream_handler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler) :

    last_entry = None
    last_name  = None


    def startElement(self, name, attrs) :
        self.last_name = name
        if name == 'item':
            self.last_entry = {}
        elif name != 'root' and name != 'updated' :
            self.last_entry[name] = {'attrs': attrs, 'content': ''}

    def endElement(self, name):

        if name == 'item':

            # YOUR APPLICATION LOGIC GOES HERE

            self.last_entry = None
        elif name == 'root':
            raise StopIteration

    def characters(self, content):
        if self.last_entry:
            self.last_entry[self.last_name]['content'] += content



parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setContentHandler(stream_handler())
with open(os.path.basename('FILENAME'), "rb") as local_file:
    for data in stream_gz_decompress(local_file):
            parser.feed(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to use sax with untangle?, mean that I load the file by sax and read it by untangle , because I have a lot of code wrote using untagle and I developped since long times , and I don't want to restart from scratch
Thanks

Comment: not an answer. Should be deleted and put as a comment